# Terminal path tcl

Tags: tcl, ns2

Hy guy i tried to invoke this tcl in the terminal but it gave me this error

```
num_nodes is set 0
warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl
can't read "node_(0)": no such variable
while executing
"$node_(0) set X_ 133.516460138239"
(file "/tmp/mob.tcl" line 4)
invoked from within
"source.orig /tmp/mob.tcl"
("uplevel" body line 1)
invoked from within
"uplevel source.orig [list $fileName]"
invoked from within
"if [$instance_ is_http_url $fileName] {
set buffer [$instance_ read_url $fileName]
uplevel eval $buffer
} else {
uplevel source.orig [list $fileName]
..."
(procedure "source" line 8)
invoked from within
"source  "/tmp/mob.tcl" "
(file "mobilita_source.tcl" line 125)
```

#### And the tcl file is

## # Define ions

```
   set val(chan)    Channel/WirelessChannel     ;# channel type
   set val(prop)    Propagation/TwoRayGround    ;# radio-propagation model
   set val(netif)   Phy/WirelessPhy         ;# network interface type

   set val(mac) Mac/802_11           ; # MAC type
     Mac/802_11 set RTSThreshold_ 500  ;            
     Mac/802_11 set dataRate_ 24Mb   ;
     Mac/802_11 set basicRate_ 6Mb   ;
     Mac/802_11 set CWMin_ 31    ;
     Mac/802_11 set CWMAX_ 1023  ;
     Mac/802_11 set SlotTime_ 0.000009 ;    
     Mac/802_11 set SIFS_ 0.000016    ;
     Mac/802_11 set ShortRetryLImit_ 7 ;
     Mac/802_11 set LOngRetryLimit_ 7  ;


     set val(ifq)   Queue/DropTail/PriQueue     ;# interface queue type
     set val(ifqlen)        50              ;# max packet in ifq
     set val(ll)    LL              ;# link layer type
     set val(ant)   Antenna/OmniAntenna     ;# antenna model
     set val(adhocRouting)   AODV           ;# routing protocol


      set val(x)        250             ;# X dimension of the topography
      set val(y)        250             ;# Y dimension of the topography

      set val(tr)       esercizio1.tr       ;# trace file
      set val(rate)           [lindex $argv 0]  ;
      set val(nn)             [lindex $argv 1]        ;# how many nodes are simulated
      set val(stop)     [lindex $argv 3]    ;# simulation time
      set val(seed)     0.0
```

## # Main Program

```
# Initialize Global Variables

# create simulator instance

 set ns_        [new Simulator]

 # define topology

 set topo   [new Topography]
 $topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)

 # create trace object for ns and nam

 set tracefd    [open $val(tr) w]

 $ns_ trace-all $tracefd



 $ns_ use-newtrace 



 # Create God

 set god_ [create-god $val(nn)]         

 # define how node should be created

 #global node setting

  $ns_ node-config  -adhocRouting $val(adhocRouting) \
     -llType $val(ll) \
     -macType $val(mac) \
     -ifqType $val(ifq) \
     -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
     -antType $val(ant) \
     -propType $val(prop) \
     -phyType $val(netif) \
     -channelType $val(chan) \
     -topoInstance $topo \
     -agentTrace ON \
     -routerTrace ON \
     -macTrace ON


   #  Create the specified number of nodes [$val(nn)] and "attach" them  to the channel

  for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
  set node_($i) [$ns_ node] 
  }


  # Define node positions

   source  "/tmp/mob.tcl" 

  # Define traffic flows

  source "traffic"

  for {set i 0} {$i < 4 } {incr i} {

  $cbr_($i) set interval_ [ expr 1 /$rate ]

  }




  # Tell nodes when the simulation ends

  for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
  $ns_ at $val(stop).000000001 "$node_($i) reset";
  }

  $ns_ at $val(stop).000000001 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"


  puts "Starting Simulation..."
  $ns_ run
```

i invoked the ns mobilita_source from terminal but it describe me this so i think it could be for the path /tmp in the mobilita_souce.tcl file. In tmp i noticed that the file is present.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `node_(0)` is not set, so the variable is unreadable. That means that the code to set it did not run, perhaps because the variable `val(nn)` contains `0`, or perhaps because it contains something other value — possibly non-numeric — that sorts less than `1`; *the empty string is such a value*. The value of `val(nn)` comes from `lindex $argv 1`, so it is the second argument after the Tcl script that you passed to the executable to invoke the program (assuming it's tclsh-like).

If there are insufficient arguments, you'll get an empty string from the `lindex` (for backward-compatibility reasons, and out-of-range `lindex` produces an empty string instead of throwing an error). You are advised to explicitly check that sufficient arguments were passed in:

```
if {[llength $argv] < 4} {
    error "missing arguments, needs: rate, nn, ??, seed"
}
```

You can then (assuming Tcl 8.5 or 8.6) use `lassign` to write those to variables; it's a little clearer than a bunch of `set … [lindex $argv …]` and easier to get correct:

```
# your posted code ignores one argument...
lassign $argv val(rate) val(nn) ?? val(seed)
```

In 8.4 and before (outdated versions now) then you'd instead do:

```
foreach $argv {val(rate) val(nn) ?? val(seed)} break
```

But that's really not very clear.